# Black screen TTYs1-6 (KDE)

Tags: debian, kde, tty

Since I installed KDE and removed Gnome, when I switch to any TTY1-6 I got a black screen. Switching back to TTY7 works fine.

I don't know why is this happening, but I guess that some needed package was removed when Gnome was removed.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: How about `getty`s? Are they still there and starting upon init on the first 6 VTs? (E.g. look in `pstree` for them). Their startup is configured in `/etc/inittab` just in case (you're probably interested in multi-user runlevel).

Comment: @Bob I see 6*[getty] but no childs. In `/etc/inittab` there are these lines: `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1`, `2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2`, 3-6 = 2

Comment: This seems ok. Hm... once I had the same with my Ubuntu 10.04. Have you seen: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen

Comment: @Bob it didn't fix it. I think the problem wasn't switch from Gnome to KDE, I think the problem was upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie. After I did so, when shutting down the system I don't see the typical log which shows which services are being stopped and so. The screen remains black, exactly as black as when switching to TTYs.

Comment: Just noticed that they are working. I logged and created a folder, and the switch back to X and there is that folder.

Comment: Umm... Congrats! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug in kernel 3.9 using fglrx.

Bug report and workaround -> http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712527

The problem was upgrade to Jessie rather than remove Gnome.